# Testing Android market licensing with different publisher account

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I am developing an Android app on behalf of a client. Since there's no facility for allowing multiple logins for a publisher account, the client prefers me not to have access to the publisher account, since that would give me access to the Google Checkout account and other sensitive information. The client has asked me to send the APKs for him to upload.

This is fine, but I need to be sure that the licensing works correctly. My plan is to have my own separate publisher account, and use its public key for testing the licensing implementation. Then, when I'm confident it's working, all I have to do is get the client to send me the public key from his publisher account, and I swap it in.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Are there likely to be problems with uploading the APK to my test account first, even if I never publish it from this account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make sure that the apk you upload has a different package name than the one that will be uploaded for your client.